# When do you use the Lambda function? And why usually user with map(), filter() function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, filter

I studied that lamda function can be used immediately and discarded where it is needed. What is the relationship between map, filter and lamda?

```
wins = map(lambda x : 'img' + str(x), range(5))
wins = list(wins)
```

Comment: It's not a lambda function, it's a lambda *expression*, which is just another way to define a function without having to bind it to a name.

Comment: There is no relation to `map` or `filter`, aside from the fact that a lambda expression can produce a value suitable for the first argument to either `map` or `filter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

Comment: lambda is for making "throwaway" functions, that you only really need to use once perhaps, and don't care for afterwards. That's it. map and filter accept "functions" as one of the arguments. That's essentially the extent of their relation to lambda, there's no real reason why map or filter must use lambdas in particular. You use a lambda if it makes sense, otherwise you use a traditional function.

Comment: I'd also challenge the 'usually used with map', I never use map/filter, but use plenty of lamdas

Comment: @chepner what is a lambda function then?

Comment: @Chris_Rands There's no such thing, aside from being a term used by people who think that lambda expressions and `def` statements produce fundamentally different objects.

Answer (score 1):

`lambda` is often used when there is a better/more efficient solution. While there are places to use `lambda` this isn't the most efficient or pythonic solution.

I'd suggest a list comprehension here as it's more readable and efficient for what you're doing.

```
>>> wins = [f'img{n}' for n in range(5)]
>>> wins
['img0', 'img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4']
```

If your version of python doesn't support `f-strings` use `str.format`

```
wins = ['img{}'.format(n) for n in range(5)]
```

Or if you want to use `map` then `str.format` works here too:

```
wins = list(map('img{}'.format, range(5)))
```

Comment: disagree, there are lots of valid uses for `lambda`, e.g. as a key function for `sorted()` or `itertools.groupby()` etc.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't have it's uses but here it's absolutely not necessary. I was referring to how many times it's used when there are better options.

Comment: Replace "usually" with "often", and I'll agree with this a lot more. `lambda` expressions are overused, whether by pairing it with `map` when a list comprehension would be preferable, or when used to add a layer of indirection around something that could be used more efficiently by itself (e.g., `lambda x: int(x)` instead of simply `int`).

Comment: My apologies, I must have worded it wrong. Often is a better word @chepner! Thanks, that was my initial intent